# Should I put tempo change markers only on midi track in this case drums or on master track?

Tags: drums, tempo

How will recording other instruments be affected by where I put the tempo changing markers? I'm using Mixcraft Studio Pro 8

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: mixcraft studio pro 8

Answer (score -1):

Master track. Tempo changes are pretty much a master track kind of thing.  Didn't see the other part of the question until now.  It really shouldn't affect the instruments or the way you record them, other than whatever notes entered will be played back at the speed you set the tempo to.  What DAW are you using?  I think the principles are going to carry over to every DAW, but you never know until you check.  If you make a tempo change and want to live record midi into that section, it should play back exactly how you recorded on any track in the project.  The other tracks or instruments are slaves to the master track, so they all follow whatever the master track is set to.

Comment: This doesn't answer the important part of this question - which is how it will affect other instruments...